# c# - Failed to enable constraints when filling datatable

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I'm trying to fill the datatable, but I get an error saying: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

I've allowed NULL values for a column and some records have to have NULL values (it's a date field btw.)

How can I fill the datatable and still allowing the NULL values for that field?

Comment: can u post some code?

Comment: Well it's really just this:
try {
  taTable.Fill(dsSomething.dtAnything);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{ ... }

Comment: This is just weird.. Restarted VS2013 and now it's working fine... Really hate this. :)